# Button click has to be in order in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons in the same form one is submit and another is save to CM , I want to give an alert if the user is just clicking the save to CM button with out first clicking the search button . I am calling the same js function for both of these onclick event just by passing a variable which says what is clicked

```
function setAction(var)
if (var == action)
{
}
else // save to cm 
{
}
```

I tried so many ways but nothing is working 
1. I tried to include a hidden variable in the form and changed the  hidden variable value in the if( var ==search ) , but when I clicked the save to cm again it is going to the function again like a new call and will not be able to get the previous function call value

```
  if (action == 'save to cm')
    {
        if(document.getElementById('searchButtonClicked').value==='notclicked')
            {
            alert(document.getElementById('searchButtonClicked').value);
            alert('Please search for the physician before saving to Content 
            Manager');
            return false;
            }
      }
```

the above condition is always true

2. I tried to disable the button initially when the page loads

and in the search action function I tried to enable the button like below 
document.getElementById('saveToCm').removeAttribute("disabled");

but this one not enabling the button at all . Any help is appreciated

The following is the jsp , i tried to delete some code since it is too huge

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />

<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/styles.css"/>" type="text/css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var specialDates = {};
  var now = new Date();
  specialDates['10' + now.getMonth() + '' + now.getFullYear()] = [true, 'mg-special', 'By Manager'];
  specialDates['25' + now.getMonth() + '' + now.getFullYear()] = [true, 'as-special', 'By Associate'];
  var others = [true, '', ''];
  $("#dateOfSleepStudy").datepicker({

    'beforeShowDay': function(date) {
      var target = date.getDate() + '' + date.getMonth() + '' + date.getFullYear();
      return specialDates[target] || others;
    },
    'inline': true
  });
});
</script>


<script>



    if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}





    function setAction(action) {

        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
         var letters = /[A-Za-z]+$/;  
          var datevalFormat =/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;

        if (action == 'SEARCH') {           
            document.getElementById('action').value = action;
            alert(  document.getElementById('saveToCm').disabled);


    //$("#saveToCm").prop("disabled",false);
      // document.getElementById('saveToCm').removeAttribute("disabled");

            //document.getElementById('saveToCm').disabled = false;
alert(document.getElementById('saveToCm').disabled);
            document.getElementById('searchButtonClicked').value = 'clicked';
             return checkMandatoryAttribute();      
    } else {
            alert(document.getElementById('saveToCm').disabled);alert('save to cm');

        }
        document.getElementById('action').value = action;
        return true;
    }




    function checkMandatoryAttribute()
    {
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
         var letters = /[A-Za-z]+$/;  
          var datevalFormat =/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;

    if (document.getElementById('lastName').value.trim() == '') {
                alert('Last Name is required.');
                return false;
            } 
    return true;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<DIV class=headerImg align=left></DIV>
<br/>
<table style="width:1200px" class="form">

    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <form:form name="SearchForm" commandName="searchForm" action="Search.do" method="post">
                <table style="width:100%;BORDER-BOTTOM: #6699cc 1px dotted">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" align="left"> Last Name</td>
                        <td><form:input  path="lastName" maxlength="50" cssClass="textBox"/></td>
                        <td class="label" align="left">First Name</td>
                        <td><form:input  path="firstName" maxlength="50"  cssClass="textBox"/></td>
                        <td class="label" align="left">State</td>
                        <td><form:input  path="state" maxlength="50" cssClass="textBox"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="label" align="left">NPI</td>
                        <td><form:input path="npi" maxlength="50" cssClass="textBox"/></td>
                        <td class="label" align="left">City</td>
                        <td><form:input path="city" maxlength="50" cssClass="textBox"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="label" align="left">Date </td>
                        <td><form:input  id ="dateOfSleepStudy" path="dateOfSleepStudy" cssClass="textBox" required pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}"/></td>                        
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td><form:hidden path="action"/></td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="search" id="physsearchBtn" name="physsearchBtn" class="buttonDis" onclick="return setAction('SEARCH')"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Reset" class="buttonDis" onClick="doReset()"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>




                <table style="width:450px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="50" align="right">
                            <input type="button" name="saveToCm" id="saveToCm" value="Save To CM" class="buttonDis" disabled=true  onclick="return setAction('SAVETOCM')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I want to give an alert if the user is just clicking the save to CM button with out first clicking the search button" why would you allow the user to make this mistake in the first place?

Comment: Can you consider posting html as well??

Comment: It is the business requirement to display the buttons in the same page so I did not have a choice other than doing this validation

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is define a variable outside of your function that is set to `false`. Inside the conditional logic for your search button being clicked, set this variable to `true`. Then simply run check that this value is `true` inside of the conditional for your `save` button being clicked.

This way, `search` **must** be clicked before `save` to trigger the `save` logic, as is seen in the following example:

```js
var search_clicked = false;

function setAction(action) {
  if (action == 'search') {
    search_clicked = true;
    console.log("Search was clicked");
  }
  if (action == 'save') {
    if (search_clicked == true) {
      // This will only trigger when search has already been clicked
      console.log("Both buttons were clicked");
    }
    else {
      console.log("You need to click search first");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setAction('search')">Search</button>
<button onclick="setAction('save')">Save</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you , but this is not working in my case , the global variable is not assigning to true . I think because the fucntion is getting called again like brand new and it is taking the global variable default value .

Comment: Are your buttons dynamically generated (created after the page loads)? Are you including `return` in your function? Can you edit your question to include your HTML please? The function might be being referenced incorrectly. As long as the variable is **outside** of the function, the above code will work. My sample code is working, so I suggest starting with that, and then slowly adding your code in until it breaks. Then you'll know exactly why it isn't working for you =]

Comment: Yes my function returns true or false , I tried like that . given alerts in search before and after assigning and then in saveto cm i alerted the value it is always what we set in the global var

Comment: Looking at your added HTML code, I think I've cracked it. You're calling your search function `setAction('SEARCH')`. This **won't** trigger `if (action == 'search')`, as it's **case-sensitive**. Try `setAction('search')`, making sure that the parameters match the conditionals **exactly**. If the `console.log()` inside of `if (action == 'search')` isn't triggering, it means that the condition isn't being met, and thus the functionality won't work. Making `SEARCH` lowercase should fix this issue =]

Comment: Thank you but that is not the problem because i used same cases everywhere, I took help from Spring mvc and just introduced a new model attribute and saved the attribute value to true in java script function and eventually it retained that value , However I still don't have the just javascript methodology to achieve this .

Comment: Use `console.log()` and the F12 Developer Tools to further debug the problem. As I said in the last comment, if the `console.log()` inside of the conditional isn't triggering, it means the conditional isn't being hit. The conditionals **must** match the function parameters **exactly**. This is almost definitely why your code isn't working. Can you confirm if the `Search was clicked` log is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I think all of three measures are valid, but your implements may have some faults in detail.

For example, in your first idea, had you recorded your button status with a global variation? 
The correct handle procedures are: 
the first button been clicked --> sign with the global variation --> the second button been clicked --> check the global variation --> if the global variation been signed then execute its function

In your second idea, had you set your property of "input" as [type="submit"]? If its type is submit, it will submit your form, so you can't get your call value. The correct type is "button".

Your description is not accurate enough.If possible, paste your whole code please.

Comment: Thank you , I am going to try the second one because I specified as submit and not button , let me try that . But for the first scenario what do you mean by sign with global variation ? you mean assign the variable to some other value and then check that value in save to cm button ?

Comment: I reckon @Obsidian Age has committed the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy if you use jQuery.
Use `.data()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Search button clicked');
    $('#search').data('clicked', true);
  });
  $('#save').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Save button clicked');
    if ($('#search').data('clicked')) {
      //  do something
      console.log('Success..!!!');
    } else {
      // do something
      console.log('Click on Search button to continue');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='search'>Search</button>
<button id='save'>Save</button>
```